# How to create features for site configuration in drupal 7

Tags: 7, features

I have one requirement where all admin configuration need to be converted in to features eg caching must be enable

Answer (score 2):

[Strongram](https://drupal.org/project/strongarm) module will allow to export system configurations and settings through features.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Configuration Management](https://drupal.org/project/configuration) module, which is under active development and tries to implement Drupal 8 way of configuration management in Drupal 7. It is worth to take a look.

> The configuration management module enables the ability to keep track
>   of specific configurations on a Drupal site, provides the ability to
>   move these configurations between different environments (local, dev,
>   qa, prod), and also move configurations between completely different
>   sites (migrate configurations) without the use of modules with all
>   configuration being owned by the site.